# Network manager forgets wireless password after sleeping or powering off

Tags: wireless, 11.10, network-manager

Every time I restore my computer from sleep or turn it on a window pops up asking for my wireless password. Once I enter it it connects successfully, but this happens every time. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with all updates installed. Shouldn't the password be remembered so you don't have to enter it every time I get on?

Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Could `pm-powersave` be the cause of your problem? My answer to [http://askubuntu.com/questions/65001/how-to-connect-wirelessly-in-a-cafe-with-11-04/65606#65606](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65001/how-to-connect-wirelessly-in-a-cafe-with-11-04/65606#65606) might apply:

Comment: any progress? same issue here

Comment: I have this problem as well. When I first boot up my laptop computer, my computer logs in to my wireless network without any problem automatically. If I close the lid on my my laptop/suspend/hibernate computer, I keep getting prompted for my wireless network password, even though the prompt for my network actually shows that it has my password saved. My network connection properties also have the network settings saved for all users. It doesn't matter what desktop environment I use. Both Gnome 3.6 and Unity have the same problem. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had the same problem. To fix this. Go to your network connections. From there click on wireless tab. Choose your connection and then click the edit button. Make sure your password is entered then click on the wireless security tab. Then check the box in the bottom left corner that says available to all users. This is what fixed the problem for me.

Comment: YES! This fixed the problem! Oh my goodness, you just made my day! :) This has been bugging me for SO long.

Comment: That would store the password outside of your user directory, right?

Comment: This is not an option for me. I want to have a guest account without password, but I do not want them to see all of my wireless passwords. The password for my university wifi can be used also elsewhere, so I have to keep it really secret.

Comment: any option tom make it not ask, just retry with stored password... btw knetwork-manager just connect, not asks, it is only gnome

Comment: Didn't work for me. Stupid prompt keeps pinging me for my password

Comment: Does not work, this morning came and saw it had popped up over 100 times! It seems this bug has not been fixed since 2011. The real problem was that external antenna was not connected and signal was weak, but popups are the most annoying piece of software they should be banned.

Comment: This solution works for me too. More, this solves a GDM issue when I started my computer, I could not enter my password to login me since a modal network popup blocked the password field.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slight variation of Hugo's answer. For me the problem was occuring with a particular network despite the "All users may connect to this network" checkbox being already checked. So what I did was to uncheck the box, save, check the box, then save again. I know this seems retarded, but it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the edit connections tab and look in wireless security. Is your password there. if not enter it and it should stay there.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue for me was weak signal, I attached an external antenna to fix that.
This is a bug and no workaround worked for me.
It seems to be related to the gnome keyring, but I could not figure out why it pops up while the box is filled in (i.e. password is saved).

Comment: Had the same problem in Debian with OlinuXino. This answer helped me a lot, because I forgot to attach the antenna O:-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an automatic login or du you need to type your password into lightdm when you start your computer? In a previous ubuntu version I had a similar issue and removing the automatic login did the trick. This is/was some strange security policy and I don't know if this solution will work for Ubuntu 11.10 / Gnome 3 but maybe this still works.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably related [to this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/854833)

I have a variant of the bug, in which it created multiple prompts, but after a while managed to connect... turns out that in my case the issue was due to some duplicate connection configs of the same wifi

Answer (score -7):

I don't know how to fix that behavior but I do know an alternative method of security that's not as strong as the password but will still keep the many unwanted users off your network and not query you on every boot up. Set up MAC address blocking in your router and disable the password. Open up your browser and connect to the router. Frequently http://192.168.1.1, a router password will also be required. You'll then be able to look through the router's menu tree to find where it configures MAC address blocking. It's a good idea to set your router password to something other than the default. On my TRENDnet router the default password was "admin." You can find the correct IP and default password in the documentation that came with your router. If you can't find it you can download a new manual from the manufacturer.

Comment: That is a terrible idea. It is the equivalent of fixing an issue with a front door that keeps locking you out by removing the lock and planting a tree in front of the door, hoping that nobody will notice the house...

Comment: I don't have reputation on askubuntu.com enough to vote it down, but I would definitely do that if I could.

Comment: I've made a suggestion that works with a caution that you're less protected than with a password. It isn't to Bart's liking so it's appropriate to recommend against my answer but to vote down a correct answer is hardly appropriate.

Comment: For everybody reading this: DON'T DO THAT! MAC addresses can be spoofed EASILY. Anyone can put its wireless card in promiscuous mode near your house, capture a few packets, take note of MAC addresses in the network and then replace its own MAC with a valid one to have full access to your network. WEP is not an option, MAC filtering is not an option, just WPA/WPA2 provide an acceptable level of security today.

Comment: It's not a correct answer. The questions were "Shouldn't the password be remembered so you don't have to enter it every time I get on? Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?".

The problem isn't that it's less secure than a password, it's that it's not secure *at all*.