# Network manager forgets wireless network key

Tags: 11.10, wireless, network-manager

Every time my computer logs out from inactivity, I have to enter the network key for my wireless network. I don't see any "remember" checkbox. Is there a way to get Ubuntu to remember the network key? It seems to remember the networks and which one is preferred etc. This started when I upgraded to 11.10; it had worked properly prior to upgrading.

Comment: May be this link can help http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-asks-for-wireless-password-continually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the network icon in the panel and choose *Edit connections...*
Go to the wireless tab, select your network and click edit.
On the *Wireless security* tab, make sure the password field isn't empty.

Comment: Its not empty. I made sure. about 20 times each time i saw its again empty.
Its forgeting- it cant save- so its empty..

Comment: @Kangarooo, checkout qweeak's comment to the question for a workaround

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug report about this problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/877803

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: The problem is not directly related to this bug report - for a work around to the problem described in the question see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-asks-for-wireless-password-continually

Answer (score 0):

The problem though is, if your particular router ever entires a bad state and stalls/denies a connection (as my aging router does) Network Manager loses the saved password. I haven't found a solution to this problem.

Edit: You may want to look into the WICD network manager as a replacement for the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 10.04.03 just yesterday. Installed and put latest updates and made new user. The problem was with this new user, not on main user.
So the second user has this problem and removing network and adding again did not help, and removing keyring folder also did not help and not even removing keyring password.

For now I have a solution to get everything working quickly at the cost of making yet another user:
Using `sudo nautilus` I copied the whole home directory (so that all hidden files and folders are copied, too) to a new location and deleted the user and made a new user with the same name -- now it did not even ask for keyring but it is good enough for me -- I have no problem changing the password in case someone sees my wifi password.