# "Wireless authentification" appears even when wep key is saved

Tags: 11.10, wireless, authentication

In Ubuntu 11.10 dialog Box "Wireless authentification requiered" appears even when the wep key it's alraedy saved in system.
That appears when I lost wireless connection and the system retry to connect
It's annoying to click accept each time I'm connecting to a network.
What I need to do so that dialog box does not appear more?

Comment: This is a FAQ:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot

Comment: may be this link can help http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-asks-for-wireless-password-continually

Answer (score 1):

The wep key password is stored in network manager. The application that is throwing out the dialog box "Wireless authentification requiered" is gnome-keyring

see: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring

The link I gave you discusses how to disable this feature.