# password reconnecting to wireless network Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, password

[image]
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-classic, and every time the wireless goes down, be it because I lose signal or some other reason, my laptop automatically tries to reconnect but I am asked to confirm the wireless password details in a window like this:

```
Authentication required by wireless network
Password or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'abc1234'.

Password: *********

Cancel / OK
```

The password is saved in the system, I don't have to type it again, but the window keeps popping up for every reconnection and I need to click the 'OK' button every time. Is there a way to avoid having to click 'OK' every time it tries to reconnect, since the password is already stored in the system?

Comment: The link below treat the same problem. Try it.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-asks-for-wireless-password-continually

Answer (score 1):

I met the same question as you on Ubuntu12.04 platform.

I check `modprobe` and found that there are two module conflict with my wireless network card, which is `rtl8192cu` and `rtl8192c_common`.

You can user `lsmod` to check the module.

I add these to context into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist rtl8192c_common
```

then I reinstall my wireless network driver and reboot, and finally I can access the Internet.