# Cannot connect to wifi after downloading 12.04, repeated prompts for password

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have had this OS for a little bit but this is my first upgrade and my first issue I am trying to deal with without my buddy who got my on Ubuntu in the first place (who is on the other side of the country.)

I am running an IBM Lenovo T400 Thinkpad that had 11.10 on it and worked flawless.  I upgraded to 12.04 a few weeks back and I have not been able to connect to the WiFi in my home or anywhere for that matter.  I have been trying to mess with it through reading the forums and am not quite sure what my problem is.  I am running off of Fios Internet and the WiFi keep disconnecting and prompts me to retype the password for reconnecting. If you guys could give me a step by step process of how I should go about fixing this I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-asks-for-wireless-password-continually  - Please try the solution given for that question and see if solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears from your description to be a misbehaving network-manager. To find out more information about the problem it's important to gather up the output from network manager as it's attempting to make a connection to your wifi network.

Before you follow these instructions, please save these instructions, what we are about to do with disable your internet on the machine and you may loose the ability to read how to switch it back on if you don't save them.

The instructions to gather the information will need you to go into a command line, you can simply go to the search button in the left top corner and type in 'command', you'll see a little black screen icon called 'Terminal' click on it.

Firstly we must stop the network manager by copying and pasting this command. This will ask you for your password:

```
gksu service network-manager stop
```

Next we want to start the manager and capture the information from it:

```
gksu NetworkManager --no-daemon &> ~/Desktop/debug.txt
```

It shouldn't return you back to the prompt. Now with this running attempt to connect to your wifi service through the normal means. You should have noticed the network icon in the right corner disappear when you stopped the service and reappear when you started it again. Try a couple of times to record a few instances in the log file.

You'll notice a new file on your desktop called debug.txt, you need to send this to who-ever will be debugging your problem. In this case you should attach it to this question by editing the original question (don't post a new answer) add in the log file contents.

To start the network-manage properly you should hold [ctrl] and press [C] this should stop the special network manager service and return you to the prompt. Then simply type this command to start the normal service again:

```
gksu service network-manager start
```

We'll work out what your problem is from there.