# I can't connect to wireless it's keep asking for authenticating code

Tags: wireless

I recently downloaded Ubuntu and installed it.  Every thing works just fine, but when I want connect to my wireless network, it says enter authenticating code.  When I enter the code correctly, 2 or 3 minutes later its want authenticating code again.  I even removed my password from my wireless settings but it want authenticating code again!

This is my first time using Linux.

Comment: What type of network card do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-asks-for-wireless-password-continually

Comment: @Aaron, no, that other question was about problems after resuming.

Comment: i dont know my laptop model is asus a42ja and my wireless is intel ..i think. i can find wireless network but i can't connect to them

Comment: plz help me..i dont know what to do

Comment: @Aaron be careful when flagging as a duplicate that it really is a duplicate. I appreciate your effort, but just be a bit more careful :)

Comment: However, these two questions are very similar. @alexander can you try the fix in the other question that Aaron suggested and let us know if it works for you?

Comment: yes i tried it but it not worked for me..i removed my password in wireless connecion, and i tried to connect without password but it tries to connect for 2 min and then it says wireless cinnection disconnected.i dont know what to do.:(

Comment: can anyone tel me how to uninstall wireless driver??could it issue from wireless driver??

Comment: plz help me!any one?