# Ubuntu not connecting to wireless after restarting networking service

Tags: wireless, networking

There was a problem with my internet connection and I thought that restarting the networking service might fix the problem. So I used `sudo service networking restart` command. However, my window manager crashed and I had to restart laptop to get it back. The problem is, ever since after that I haven't been able to connect to my WiFi. Anybody knows a solution to this?

Edit: I can see the wireless networks. When I connect to mine, Ubuntu keeps asking me for password even though I enter the right password.

Comment: Please give us more info. Do you see wireless networks but you can't connect to them? Does it keep on asking you for a password? Or does your laptop not show you any wireless networks and doesn't recognize your wireless card?

Comment: @Alaa - Please see edit.

Comment: Go to the wireless icon at the top right > Edit connections... > Delete your Wireless network, then try to connect again. If it doesn't work, take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/69181/52726) answer.

Comment: Replying from Ubuntu! :)

Thnx. You can just answer it instead of commenting so that I can accept an answer.

Comment: Which one worked for you =D? My suggestion or the answer in the other question?

Comment: Your solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wireless keeps on asking you for the password, do this:

1. Click on the wireless icon on the top right.
2. Go to **Edit Connections...**
3. Highlight and delete the wireless network you are trying to connect to.
4. Try to connect again.