# Wifi connectivity problem

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless, internet

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 to try it out on a USB stick.  I want to install it now, but I cannot get the wifi to connect.  It keeps asking for password verification.

I am not very knowledgeable with computers and have never tried a Linux OS before.  I really like what I've seen of Ubuntu so far, but I can't use Ubuntu if I can't get the internet to work...

Comment: To analyze the problem we need details of your hardware. Please edit your question and include result of following commands. Run these commands in a terminal (alt+ctrl+T) `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network`. Then try to connect to your network and execute `dmesg | tail` and post the output along with the others

Comment: Are you sure you're entering the password correctly? Can you try the steps [in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/310706/52726). If not, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `sudo service network-manager restart` and try to connect again.

Answer (score 0):

The system is most likely asking you for one of two things:
1) Your wireless WPA password
2) Your username password

Without knowing exactly where it is asking you for the password it is hard to ascertain which password it is asking for.

Either way make sure that you are issuing the correct password.