# WIFI stopped working on Xubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, xubuntu

Today I turned on my notebook and I couldn't connect to my network, it just keeps asking for my password. That's weird because I've been using it on this network forever and never saw this error.

So I restarted my router thinking that could be the problem, and nope, both my desktop computers connect fine but my notebook still can't connect.

So I boot my notebook on Windows 7 and it connects just fine, so it's not a hardware thing...

The encryption im using is WPA & WPA2 Personal, and the wireless card is RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit

Why can't I connect to wifi on my xubuntu notebook?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu gosu! **What exactly happens** when you try to connect to your network? Does it repeatedly keep asking you for the password? Does it connect, but you can't access the internet? Please provide more information.

Comment: It repeatedly keeps asking for my password

Comment: Follow the steps [in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/310706/52726). If it doesn't fix it, follow the steps [in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/69181/52726). If one of these fixes your issue, please report back on which one did.

Comment: what encryption are you using?  what wireless network card you are using?

Comment: The encryption im using is WPA & WPA2 Personal, the wireless card is RTL8111/8168 PCI EXpress Gigabit.

@Alaa: I tried both, none of them worked.

Comment: Let's continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10317/discussion-between-alaa-and-gosu-kiwi).

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KyQBCcxf Here it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out for some reason the drivers broke... I downloaded the drivers from Realtek and installed them, reboot, and it now works as a charm!

```
tar -xvzf myDriver.tar.gz
cd myDriver/
sudo make
sudo make install
reboot
```

Thanks to everyone who helped :)

EDIT: I had to follow [this guide](http://www.perseosblog.com/en/posts/solving-connection-problem-with-realtek-wifi-card-rtl8188ce-rtl8192ce-rtl8191se-and-rtl8192de-on-debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives/) for a source code error on their driver code

Comment: Could you add more information about *how* did you installed it?

Comment: Sorry I will post the formatted code in my answer