# ubuntu 12.4, wireless doesn't work after update

Tags: 12.04, wireless, iwlwifi

the wireless is not working after update, it can see the wireless networks around, put it can't connect, and keep asking for the password, and sometimes it cause kernel panic

this is the wireless info

```
*************** info trace ***************


***** uname -a *****


Linux marwan-ThinkPad-T410 3.2.0-53-generic-pae #81-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 21:23:47 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux


***** lsb_release *****


Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise


***** lspci *****


00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2153]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:e020]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se


***** lsusb *****


Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:480f Lenovo Integrated Webcam [R5U877]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1d57:0008  


***** PCMCIA Card Info *****




***** iwconfig *****


wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off



***** rfkill *****


0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


***** lsmod *****


wl                   2906597  0 
lib80211               14040  1 wl
rtl8192se              94189  0 
rtlwifi                95855  1 rtl8192se
mac80211              436493  2 rtl8192se,rtlwifi
cfg80211              178877  3 wl,rtlwifi,mac80211


***** nm-tool *****


NetworkManager Tool


State: connected (global)


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192se
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>


  Capabilities:


  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes


  Wireless Access Points 
    davidgamal:      Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 62 WPA
    a7a:             Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA
    NaDoUsHa:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA
    essam:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA
    Magdy:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA
    linksys:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA
    elguindy:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA
    NETGEAR:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA
    fakhry:          Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    apad:            Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 42 WPA
    Vodafone_ADSL_4810: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WEP
    Vodafone_ADSL_93A0: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 42 WEP
    eSEED:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 62 WPA WPA2
    m&n:             Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA
    zeyad:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA




- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>


  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s


  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on


  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.70
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254


    DNS:             192.168.1.254






***** NetworkManager.state *****


[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true


***** NetworkManager.conf *****


[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq


[ifupdown]
managed=false


***** interfaces *****


auto lo
iface lo inet loopback




***** iwlist *****


wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"apad"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000022f4e6cd0c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 780ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000461706164
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"eSEED"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:9 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000642ee3c2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 408ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00056553454544
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C183048
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32041224606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010008FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00037F0301000000F8D1119777BFFAD1119777BF64002C010808
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"davidgamal"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000101f028d1bc
                    Extra: Last beacon: 344ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A646176696467616D616C
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"a7a"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000008aa0f251bc
                    Extra: Last beacon: 452ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0003613761
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"essam"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000249105e187
                    Extra: Last beacon: 188ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0005657373616D
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030109
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4304000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706545700010B10
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Magdy"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000b1227c14f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00054D61676479
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0106
                    IE: Unknown: 32048C98B060
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4304000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555300010B10
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"linksys"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001e01018156
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00076C696E6B737973
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0103
                    IE: Unknown: 32088C129824B048606C
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETGEAR"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000011860c20186
                    Extra: Last beacon: 140ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00074E455447454152
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0102
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0102
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD060010180202F4
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 09 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"zeyad"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000c022279cd
                    Extra: Last beacon: 808ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00057A65796164
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010002
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
          Cell 10 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"fakhry"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000038b98ba304
                    Extra: Last beacon: 544ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000666616B687279
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 0706545700010B14
                    IE: Unknown: 33082001020304050607
                    IE: Unknown: 33082105060708090A0B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010002
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E1117FF000000010000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1604000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4304000000




***** resolv.conf *****


nameserver 127.0.0.1
search lan


***** blacklist *****


[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci


[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma


[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac


***** modinfo *****


filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-53-generic-pae/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     620417839200A53FF5C4AB5
alias:          pci:v*d*sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
depends:        cfg80211,lib80211
vermagic:       3.2.0-53-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string


filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-53-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192S/8191S 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     DBF9BFEC2956537D0AFADA5
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008174sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008173sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008172sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008171sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008192sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-53-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)


filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-53-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     39AC859A4E18FE3AF485A4D
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-53-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 




***** udev rules *****


# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"


# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0 (rtl8192se)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"


***** dmesg *****


[   19.933281] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   19.933341] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   19.956722] rtl8192se: rtl8192ce: FW Power Save off (module option)
[   19.977495] rtl8192se: Driver for Realtek RTL8192SE/RTL8191SE
[   19.977497] Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
[   20.285621] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   20.288384] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   21.201041] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   21.201472] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   25.727929] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed> (try 1)
[   25.729536] wlan0: authenticated
[   25.749427] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1)
[   25.751323] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 6)
[   27.847644] IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3


****************** done ******************
```

i know there is a lot of threads around this problem, but i have tried a lot of solutions and nothing works.
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/310706/52726. If that doesn't help, please read the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/69181/52726. If any of these worked, please post back here and inform us which one worked. If none of them worked, please post back here as well telling us it didn't work.

Comment: Check this Solution


  http://askubuntu.com/questions/432053/how-to-enable-wifi-in-dell-5520-on-ubuntu-12-04-32-64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: Worked for me too, but no idea why. What does Broadcom has to do with Realtek?

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution to this is to remove the network manager and install wicd

**Here is how to make the switch:**

**First**, install WICD. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

**Second**, uninstall NetworkManager.

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove network-manager
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: i think you are right, i did it, and i removed the link, because the solution is too simple