# No wifi Ubuntu 12.04 Toshiba satellite P775-S7100

Tags: 12.04, wireless, toshiba

Does anyone know how to get WiFi working on my Toshiba satellite P775-S7100?

My Ethernet works fine, just no WiFi, which works fine on my windows partition.

Comment: Can you please detail what you have tried and what specifically you have a problem with? Also, please tell us your wireless card model and the output of `sudo lshw -v`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ubuntu 12.4, wireless doesn't work after update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345031/ubuntu-12-4-wireless-doesnt-work-after-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to press a button on the top of the laptop to turn the wifi adapter on. Thanks for all the replies.