# Netgear AC Wireless Adapter A6100 sill not working in Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I've tried all the answers I've followed here so far.  It was difficult to see instructions that spelled out how to download and install the driver for this wireless adapter for my PC but the worst part was that the way the instructions were written made me feel they were written for some folks who have a much better understanding of the sudo instructions.

the rtl8812au driver, is a good example:  is that RTL or RT1 ... being nearsighted I spent 15 minutes typing it in as a number instead of the lower case letter L.

and the instructions left out spacing as if I had any idea what I was doing and would already know to leave the spaces in, or put the -v between the rtl8812au and the version number.

I finally got it to install, restarted my pc and it still doesn't recognize the adapter as being there. not as a bluetooth device, and not as a wireless one either.

Can I please ask that someone among you tech savvy people give me step by step instructions that will get this thing working with Ubuntu 18.04.3?

and please, explain if there is any confusion that might occur if there is a letter involved that I might confuse for a number?

I need your help, since I'm working on a farm in the middle of nowhere, Misery (Missouri)

thank you in advance.

Comment: hi @micheal-rainwater I've just posted an answer, with detailed steps, as described in GitHub repo. If you run into any issues, please update your post with error messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the latest drivers from this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`

As per the repo, this is how you can install the drivers using DKMS method:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Your USB WiFi adapter should be working now.

Comment: well, that got it working so it can see my cell phone at least. but it still won't connect to the internet and keeps asking for my network password, cycling over and over.  I saw where someone else had asked about that and was told it would be another issue so I'll look for that answer. oh, almost forgot to say, thank  you. it did install the driver so the A6100 must be working.

Comment: @micheal-rainwater the issue could be anything from "making wireless available to all users in network manager" to "power management". Here are few threads you should go through: `https://askubuntu.com/a/69181/928088`; `https://askubuntu.com/a/360216/928088` and `https://askubuntu.com/a/509479/928088`

Comment: Thank you for the input Jags.  I have followed all 3 links you provided here, with the same results.  When I select the network and settings Ubuntu wi-fi setting shows my iPhone or iPad as being available. The signal strength is shown as being excellent; but I cannot obtain any internet page whatsoever.  On an impulse and since the Bluetooth setting is directly below the wi fi setting in Ubuntu 18.04 I selected that to see if I was ‘missing’ something.  There is no Bluetooth device recognized there. Could that be my problem?

Comment: @micheal-rainwater Earlier you said, "keeps asking for my network password, cycling over and over" and in your last comment you say, "but I cannot obtain any internet page whatsoever"... so can you connect to the wireless adapter at all or no? Thanks.

Comment: That’s the weird part. It says in the wireless connection part of settings that my iPhone is there (or iPad depending on which one I have the hotspot turned in for) and shows that there is a signal and that the signal strength is excellent. But upon opening Firefox, no matter what website I try to navigate to I get the message that the page cannot be found, I should check my internet connection, etc ... how does a tower with no WiFi recognize my phone but not show the Bluetooth WiFi connector?

Comment: @micheal-rainwater do you use network manager? What happens, when you click on wifi icon on the taskbar, and click on your iphone/ipad name from the available wifi list? Also, can you please post the output of: `cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver` Thanks.

Comment: Jags, I can take a screenshot and add a jpeg to this effort if you would think it could help. I did as you asked and this is the result that came back.

Comment: nameserver ::1    nameserver 127.0.0.1  but that might have been misleading as I have my iPhone plugged into a USB port presently.

Comment: i turned off the USB connection (ethernet) and am trying to send this to you now via wi fi and it seems to have worked .... but my iPhone is still plugged into the USB port.  I'm going to unplug it and use the wifi connection to my iPad only ...

Comment: And the tower fails to connect if my iPhone isn’t plugged in, so Im back to initializing the Bluetooth doggle to enable it to connect to my hotspots. It’s almost as if it was using my iPhone as a Bluetooth connector, and linking it to my iPad hot spot?

Answer (score 0):

Jags and others,

I'm 63 years of age (be 64 in June) and while I don't fail fast, I do fail often.

I give up on this wireless netgear thing.  It just doesn't seem to work for me. And you guys have much more important things to do that teach and old dawg new tricks.

I'll see if I can find PC card that plugs into my computer tower that has wireless capabilities that Ubuntu will already recognize.

Thank you for your time, you've been so much more than kind. - like the song says, I'd say you can keep the dime but you guys do this stuff for free.  That is what makes you great in my opinion..

Micheal