# 13.04 doesnt remember wired network password

Tags: networking, 13.04, password, wired

I recently updated to 13.04 version of ubuntu (kinda disapointing) and every time I boot ubuntu, I have to login to my school network, even though system should remember password (dont save password option is unchecked), it remebered in previous versions of ubuntu with no problem and there was no change in network itself. Its kinda annoying, because I switch ubuntu and win8 several times a day, does anyone encountered same problem/found a solution? I cant help it, but nothing works in this issue.

Comment: ohh, seems your using Dual Boot, what you mean by 13.04 doesn't remember? You mean when you clicked "save password" or what, please give us more info. But if you mean "Don't Save Password" is unchecked, then this might cause problems, please downgrade as they attempt to fix this or wait until they fix this, once this still happens as the next update, did you shut down Ubuntu properly, and is everything fine? Please give us more info often. Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you enter the password that need to be saved? Screenshots would be nice.

Comment: OP here, password is set in system settings - network - wired - options - 802.1x security - password. There isnt exactly option to remember password, but previous versions remembered it and there is "dont save password", which means password is saved by default.
And at every system start in login screen, tab asking for password for network appears, I have to fill password for network first, then log in with my user account.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after my upgrade to 13.04, I was able to solve it by following the directions on [this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/69181) in a thread asking about the same thing, but occurring in 11.10.  Good luck!