# Wifi is not conneting

Tags: wireless

I had installed Ubuntu 13 10 my ethernet is working fine. But when I want to connect with my Wi-Fi it ask me a key after entering the key it again ask me for the key but its not connecting to my Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-forgets-wireless-password-after-sleeping-or-powering-off

Comment: Nice, closing as duplicated of a question closed...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your router to an passwordless network and see if you can connect. If you can, then trying a different encryption type/agbn. If you can't, then it is likely your wifi card is the culprit and you would need to find new drivers or find specific answers to your specific card.