# NetworkManager not remembering passwords

Tags: network-manager

For new wireless networks that I've added recently to my Ubuntu 14.04 system, the system will not connect to them if I choose the wireless network from the drop-down menu. It does not seem to even attempt the connection, and does not prompt me for the password. If, however, I edit the connection file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, and set the `-flags` to `0` (so that the password is not stored by the agent), and add the password there, then I can connect fine. This applies to two PEAP connections and to one PSK connection that is sharing my LAN connection over WiFi.

In case it's relevant, I've switched in the last few months from XFCE to Unity.

Comment: I hope you have gone through (this)[http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-forgets-wireless-password-after-sleeping-or-powering-off] troubleshooting. Also, try re installing the NM. This post was helpful for me when I ran into this issue.

Comment: Thanks Vembu, they are shared to all users, and I tried turning it on and off again (unsuccessfully)

Comment: maybe xfce and ubuntu use different keyring manager? just hipotesis

Comment: That's a good hypothesis. But I added these networks under Unity, and even if I try and re-add them, the password is not remembered. So I need to know how to debug this...

Comment: I have a similar problem, except my password is lost within seconds of saving.  I can only connect if I do an "nmcli con up ..." fast enough in a terminal.  This is also on a PEAP connection, and I never had these troubles on Ubuntu 12.04; it started with the upgrade to 14.04

Comment: It's the same with Ubuntu 15.04 since one of the updates from this week, the thread @vembutech refered to only fixes this once - unitl the next sleep and/or reboot.