# Annoying popup wifi password in 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

Always I log into **Ubuntu 15.04** and my *wifi* network (HP-LASERJET) is in range it wants a **password** from me, despite I always save it. I have a problem just with this wifi network (it is not a printer, it is a basic AP). The only difference is, that it has a **hidden SSID**. How to force ubuntu to remember my password? I dont want to type it again and again. Thank you.

[image: annoying popup]

When I try to fix it in Network Manager -> Edit connections, I choose my network I save the password on my screen appear different popup window:
[image]

And I have to type keyring password before I want to connect to my wifi. On different networks I do not have to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network manager forgets wireless password after sleeping or powering off](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-forgets-wireless-password-after-sleeping-or-powering-off)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit :

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HP-LASERJET
```

and find the section that says

```
[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
```

and place the following on the next line.

```
psk=yourPassword
```

As a prevention for rewriteing it by system use:

```
chmod 400 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HP-LASERJET
```

Answer (score -1):

This may or may not apply, but I suspect that if you open your Internet connection icon at the top of the screen and select "edit connections" you might be able to select your printer, press "edit..." and check the box marked "connect automatically".  I realize it is probably already checked, but maybe there is a way to make it apply the saved password automatically.  It might be a setting under the tab there marked "wireless security".

The reason I suspect it might not apply is that I am using an earlier version of Ubuntu and the configuration of this feature may very well have changed slightly.

Comment: I am trying to find something useful, but with no success. I edited my question a little bit.

Comment: Had you not stated the brand of your printer, I would have inquired as certain printers, particularly many of those by cannon, do not adhere to what I admit I assume are accepted rules.  Generally HP has been one of those brands I expect not to encounter this type of problem with, but I've been hearing that in very recent years, HP has gone astray.  Perhaps yours is a very new model and is being needlessly difficult?

Comment: It is a classic router,  not a printer, sorry for that SSID. On Ubuntu 14.04 it works pretty well but on 15.04 I have a problems with it.

Comment: I really appreciate you telling me that, as I have been sticking with 12.04 (primarily) as a result of so many complaints about 14.04.   I had hoped 15.04 would be less problematic, not more, so our insight educates me.  As to "classic router" I take that to mean a router which acts also as a print server.  I've had such problems with such devices I gave up on them entirely.  It seems the only stable way to have a network printer, is to buy a printer with the feature built in.  Fortunately they are becoming more common these days.

Answer (score -1):

My situation is similar to what eldergeek described, but it has some variation.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HP-LASERJET
```

Change this:

```
[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk-flags=1
```

To this:

```
[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=YourPassword
psk-flags=0
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify the connection's properties programmatically, with NetworkManager's `nmcli` utility.

Here are some useful commands (hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> for autocompletion at all times):

- To modify properties of existing connections:

  ```bash
  # sudo nmcli connection modify <connection-id> <parameter> <value>

  # to set the password:
  sudo nmcli connection modify "HP-LASERJET" 802-11-wireless-security.psk p@$$w0rd

  # to disable the network's autoconnection property:
  sudo nmcli connection modify "HP-LASERJET" connection.autoconnect no
  ```
- To list ***all*** the properties of a given connection (really much more than what you can get from the contents of a `*.nmconnection` file or the `nm-connection-editor` GUI):

  ```bash
  nmcli connection show "HP-LASERJET"

  # to reveal the hidden values:
  nmcli connection show --show-secrets "HP-LASERJET"
  ```

Source: https://linuxhint.com/expertly-use-the-ubuntu-network-manager/